# Storing Values so that it prints out certain index

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a question about storing values.

For example, if I have a list of numbers

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6},
```

how can I save that as for example, `f[x]` so that when I input `f[0]`, it prints out 1, if I input `f[1]`, it prints out 2 and so forth.

When I just use arrays or lists, I couldn't do methods like `f[0]` to print out the first # in the list.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Perhaps `f[l_, x_] := l[[x - 1]]; f[{1, 2, 3}, 0]` will do

Answer (score 1):

This function will do the job:

```
f[l_List, x_Integer] := l[[x + 1]];
```

Or you can always modify your code in a way so you don't have to do these.